# Include newline that starts with space in bash?

Tags: bash, shell

So, the text file is like this:

```
TITLE and AUTHOR                                                     ETEXT NO.

Aspects of plant life; with special reference to the British flora,      56900
 by Robert Lloyd Praeger

The Vicar of Morwenstow, by Sabine Baring-Gould                          56899
 [Subtitle: Being a Life of Robert Stephen Hawker, M.A.]

Raamatun tutkisteluja IV, mennessä Charles T. Russell                    56898
 [Subtitle: Harmagedonin taistelu]
 [Language: Finnish]

Raamatun tutkisteluja III, mennessä Charles T. Russell                   56897
 [Subtitle: Tulkoon valtakuntasi]
 [Language: Finnish]
```

File is named GUTINDEX.ALL.

I want to search the file for strings. And when it finds, it should print the whole record.

So I did this:

```
#!/bin/sh
read -p 'string to search ' searchstring
grep --color "$searchstring" GUTINDEX.ALL
```

And when I search for the string 'flora'
it prints

```
Aspects of plant life; with special reference to the British flora,    56900
```

But I also want to print the new line if it starts with a blank space.
Like this:

```
Aspects of plant life; with special reference to the British flora,   56900

 by Robert Lloyd Praeger
```

Comment: Your data file has the number 56900 on the same line with flora, but your output shows it in different line.

Comment: Oh...it was a mistake while putting it in code text.

Comment: corrected  it now.

Comment: @Azazel, you wrote *if it starts with a blank space* - the crucial line does not start with a space. But the next line might have space at start. Elaborate your question

Comment: have you tried `grep -A1 <searchstring>`?

Comment: @nbari it works

Comment: @nbari, it only works for single line records and/or if you don't want to search for words in the trailing lines of the title. It will also fail when your pattern matches something in the trailing lines even if you don't want to search them.

Comment: Yeah....Just saw it. @nbari

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First read the whole record then do the search. Requires a new line at the end of the file:

```
sed -n ':l N;/^$/!tl;/'"$searchstring"'/p' input
```

Comment: Can't search with a space. Like Can't search for 'Robert Lloyd'

Comment: Updated the answer, added double quotes around searchstring.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative using AWK:

```
#!/bin/bash
awk -v term="$1" -v RS="" -v FS="\n" -v ORS="\n\n" 'tolower($0) ~ term' GUTINDEX.ALL
```

- The `-v` flag defines a few variables

  - `term` is the search term passed in from the command line
  - `RS` is the input record separator, `FS` is the field separator. The two of them together defines a record to be multiple of lines separated by a blank line
  - `ORS` is the output record separator
- The body of the AWK scripts says: convert the whole line ($0) to lowercase and see if it matches the search term. If it is, print the record
- The last argument, *GUTINDEX.ALL* specifies the input file to search

Comment: does *GUTINDEX.ALL* has blank line separating the records? The way you show your file, it seems to be the case. If it is, then my approach works.